# Display time due on Trello card instead of just the due date

Tags: trello, trello-cards

I use due dates a lot for Trello and it's great that it shows the day something is due.

I wanted to see if there is anyway to have it show the time for items that are due today (as I want that level of granularity).

I know I can drill into the card to see the details but I want to look at my today list of todos with the times all listed right there.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Trello presently does not offer a way to specify the time a card due.

*If you use Google Chrome (or Chromium)* you can install the **[Elegantt for Trello](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/elegantt-for-trello/jdongfcbejkjibhkbekkjcckophhjcjj)** extension to get the functionality you're looking for.

For better or for worse, Elegantt comes with other features, most notably a GANTT view of the cards on your board.

Here's how it looks:

1. Once the extension is installed, you may need to reload Trello in your Chrome tab, and then authorize Elegantt to connect with your Trello account

[image: Authorize Elegantt]

2. You can hide the GANTT view if you don't need it

[image: Hide GANTT]

3. On any Trello card, you'll now see the option to specify dates and times

[image: Specify Dates and Times]

Comment: The version of Ellegantt I used did not show the "time" on the face of the card.

Answer (score 0):

We added Power-Up to display due time and weekday at the front of the card.

**Show Due Time** - https://trello.com/power-ups/5f69d8caf2493015a6834e54

[image]

If you have any questions please let us know, Thanks.